# Custom tree in LDAP

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I am working now with the Apache Directory Server. I am a freshman in LDAP.
After few paragraphs of reading about it I noticed that I need my own tree to particular case that I want to design. For know, let's say I have some domain bubble.com. I want to create dc object for it dc=buble, dc=com. When I try to do so using Apache Directory Studio I get the following error:

```
Error while creating entry
 - [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     Add Request 
  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for         Add Request :
ClientEntry
    dn: dc=bubble+dc=com
    objectClass: dcObject
    objectClass: top
    dc: bubble
    dc: com
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=bubble+dc=com]; remaining name 'dc=bubble+dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3112)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3033)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(LdapCtx.java:811)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(ComponentDirContext.java:337)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:266)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper$4.run(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:658)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1272)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.checkConnectionAndRunAndMonitor(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:1203)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.jndi.JNDIConnectionWrapper.createEntry(JNDIConnectionWrapper.java:704)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.createEntry(CreateEntryRunnable.java:226)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.ldapbrowser.core.jobs.CreateEntryRunnable.run(CreateEntryRunnable.java:117)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

  [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for     Add Request :
ClientEntry
    dn: dc=bubble+dc=com
    objectClass: dcObject
    objectClass: top
    dc: bubble
    dc: com
: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=bubble+dc=com]
```

To be honest, I don't really understand what is going on. What is the idea of partitions?
Is it possible to create own dc in such way? Or maybe do I have to put everything into ou=schema or ou=system?
 What is the purpose of ou=schema and ou=system, present in ADS by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dc=bubble+dc=com` is a distinguished name with a multi-valued relative distinguished name, and no parent. The DIT must have a `suffix` or `namingContext` hosted by a backend and then you could add the entry as a subordinate to that `suffix` or `namingContext`, for example, `dc=bubble+dc=com,o=my-suffix`.

Comment: What is DIT, suffix and naming context? Documentation of Apache Directory Server really sucks and I am doing everything blindly.

Comment: DIT = directory information tree. suffix and naming context are  two names for the top level name supported by the backend, for example, in the distinguished name `ou=people,o=example`, `o=example` is the naming context or suffix. This must exist in order to add subordinates to it.

Comment: @Terry I'm having the same issue. What do you mean by backend? Did you mean web context?

Comment: Some servers (but not all) call the database hosting a "namingContext" a "backend". Server administrators will create a "backend" in a directory server configuration to host a "namingContext". In practice, a "backend" will support the data for a suffix, for example, "dc=example,dc=com". The "backend" is an LDAP server specific thing, and is not directly related to a "web context".

Comment: @Terry Let's make it simple. I'm using Apache directory studio and i managed to make a connection to Apache DS. I want to create a domain component abc.com. At 'Root DSE' icon. Want to create dc=abc,dc=com. Did that and i got that error? How would a novice LDAP person like me be able to create that dc=abc, dc=com?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know details about the configuration of Apache DS. I would suggest asking the question at server fault.

Comment: @Terry Is it under stackoverflow? Do you have the link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart apacheds service on remote server, this tutorial explains in details: https://technology.amis.nl/2014/10/22/getting-started-with-apacheds-ldap-server-and-directory-studio/

Comment: Could you add some content from the link?

Comment: If you add a partition by using apacheds studio, you need to restart apache-ds service, that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Create data partition with the suffix "dc=bubble,dc=com".
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html

Comment: please explain your solution

Comment: When you are answering a question it is highly recommended that you try to explain why the solution will work.